# Creating an Atomic RingBuffer in Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, atomic, lock-free

I was thinking of how I would go about implementing a thread-safe RingBuffer in Java and Android (as for some reason there is none, even after all these years, not even a circular queue. So, no (Circular/Ring)ByteBuffer, nor (Circular/Ring)(Buffer/Queue).

Even majority of the RingBuffer implementations that are third party are said to be not thread safe, which makes me think it really isn't as simple as I think it is going to be. What I was thinking about was doing something like this:

- Have an Object (say RingBufferPosition) that encapsulates both the Head and Tail position.
- Have the RingBuffer maintain an AtomicReference to the RingBufferPosition
- When a thread adds something, it will create a temporary (unfortunately, I don't know enough of Java to determine this, but "Stack-allocated") object, which will be recycled over and over, updating it with the new updated head and tail, until it can CAS successfully.
- When a thread removes something, it will do similar to adding something.
- Everything is accessed in an array allocated to the max length, hence, the head and tail can access/update the current element in O(1) time.

Would this work, and better yet, would it yield any benefits over simply synchronizing access to the collection?

A small code sample/pseudocode (has not been run yet, and I do not even know how to remotely test an atomic data structure, I plan on using it for buffering/streaming media but I haven't gotten that far yet as I need to create this first) can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/theif519/11c9ab26b3e507f0d7b0). I have comments/documentation that details my concerns there.

Lastly, to address a possible "Why" question, as in "Why do you need such performance", I'll be truthful. I have always found data structures, especially atomic/lock-free data structures very interesting, and I found this as a very good exercise to learn, plus I always wanted to create a Ring Buffer. I could have just "synchronized" everything, however I do also value performance.

Comment: I'm not sure how you want us to answer "would this work" when you don't have most of the details nailed down?  For what it's worth, I'd expect that a major problem will be atomically updating the index of the head/tail in the array atomically with the contents of the array itself.

Comment: What more details would I need? I have pseudocode for add() and remove() (which should be the core methods themselves, correct?). Unless there's a lot more to it that I am missing. Or is the code as well not enough?

Comment: It looks like you already have a comment expressing the concern I had, namely that you can't update the position and the array contents as one atomic operation.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm fully understanding your question, but you might want to take a look at `java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue`. It functions pretty much like a circular buffer, with different "tiers" of methods that block, return a flag or throw exceptions when the buffer is full/empty. I think that what you are trying to build may be akin to a primitive (byte) specialization of that class.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman Which is why I'm asking here. If there is another better way (or rather a way that works) I'd love to know.

Comment: @JavierMartín I wanted a non-blocking circular queue. The main reasoning is that I need a circular ByteBuffer for streaming/buffering, but I wanted to abstract to the point it can use any type at all.

Comment: If there isn't a way to do so (which I do hope there is, I do want to implement it lock-free), I'll have to make it synchronized instead, but I'll hold off on that until I know it's not possible.

Comment: @KyleStanly That's why I suggested that you took a look at the implementation - some of the methods don't necessarily block: according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) of the parent BlockingQueue, the put/take methods block, but add/remove throw an exception, while offer/take return a special value if the conditions are not met. Thus, you could forget about the blocking part and use the behaviour that you wanted.

Comment: @JavierMartín I see that peek(), poll() and offer() are non-blocking and atomic, however, as it is a queue and not a dequeue, it doesn't seem possible to overwrite old values, like I'd need to with a ring buffer. Unless of course there is a way to remove the tail of the queue once it gets too long. However, looking around, it seems that a LinkedBlockingDeque DOES have allow you to, though. Have to wonder though if I can use it as a stand in replacement.

Comment: Is it single/multiple producer/consumer? Can an operation fail or must it wait/retry until successful? Optimizations come out of understanding the use-case, e.g. a [mpsc buffer](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/caffeine/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/BoundedBuffer.java) that is striped

Comment: @BenManes I kind of need two, one generic for any type, another (which is necessary) explicitly for bytes. The one which is generic I'd like to be multiple consumer/producer, and the one for bytes single producer/consumer.

Comment: @BenManes Granted I am not far enough in my overall implementations to determine whether or not I can afford to have the RingByteBuffer to mostly just be asynchronously based on callbacks (which probably would be best), hence that one doesn't need to be single producer/consumer. It is rather embarrassing, but I'm stuck on how to implement it first and foremost before I move on. Ideally I would like to have a concrete data structure with a wrapper which calls the callbacks when it is full.

Comment: In that case you should look at [jctools](https://github.com/JCTools/JCTools) which provides optimized variations.

Comment: @BenManes I'm looking at it, but I don't see a Deque, I.E a way to get the tail of the queue. In fact, I don't see any lock-free deques for Java (a few research papers detailed in C/C++ though). I may just give up the Atomic portion for now and just go for the LinkedBlockingDeque.

Comment: There is [ConcurrentLinkedDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) which is unbounded. Since your needs aren't entirely clear, it seems better to flush out the surrounding code and then revisit this when optimizing.

Comment: @BenManes I'll take that advice. I'll try to get it stable and working first, then post back here if I have anymore questions.

Comment: My god, I just realized my crucial mistake. I kept confusing the circular buffer tail with the tail of queue (I.E what gets read next). I kept thinking of a queue as a stack. A concurrent linked queue or any other queues would work after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple reader/multiple writer ring buffers are tricky.

Your way doesn't work, because you can't update that start/end position AND the array contents atomically.  Consider adding to the buffer:  If you update the end position first, then there is a moment before you update the array when the buffer contains an invalid item.  If you update the array first, then there's nothing to stop simultaneous additions from stomping on the same array element.

There are lots of ways to deal with these problems, but the various ways have different trade-offs, and you have better options available if you can get rid of the multiple reader or multiple writer requirement.

If I had to guess at why we don't have a concurrent ring buffer in the standard library, I'd say it's because there is no one best way to implement it that is going to be good for most scenarios.  The data structure used for ConcurrentLinkedQueue, in contrast, is simple and elegant and an *obvious* choice when a concurrent linked list is required.

Comment: Decided to award as best question since it is the only answer, (although I got a ton in the comments, I can't award a comment)